# Pentaho Interactive Reporting: Add "If..Then...Else" Logic to columns

Tags: pentaho

Anyone know if we can implement the If..Then..Else logic to the columns of a data model table in Pentaho Interactive Reports, similar to the "Case" statement in SQL?

Thanks in advance,
simak

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho Interactive Reporting is part of Enterprise Edition. If you bought licence, you have access to subscribers forum and support. If you're evaluating it, you can request 30 day free support option.

As far as I know, it's possible in Pentaho Report Designer.

1. Create Report in Interactive Reporting plugin
2. Save it
3. Load the saved file in Report Designer
4. Create your field using the *Logical Expressions* - [look](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Reporting/Formula+Expressions)

[Here](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpuc_user_guide%2Ftopic_interactive_report_intro.html) is  a quote about Interactive Reports and Report Designer

Comment: Thank You fenix. Yes, I did realise we can use them in RD. But was hoping for similar functionality in the Interactive Report. But will try the approach you suggest. Regards,
Simak

Answer (score 0):

When, than the answer would be NO, it's not posible, but I suggested one way.